# X509TrustManager checkServerTrusted with TLSv1.3

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2, x509, tls1.3

I'm making a TLS client in java and using the [x509TrustManager checkServerTrusted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html#checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String)) method to validate if server certificates are trusted.

```
void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                      String authType)
                        throws CertificateException
```

`authType - the key exchange algorithm used`

The docs mention it uses an authType argument which specifies the key exchange algorithm used. This makes sense for TLS1.2 since the key exchange algorithm can be figured out from the selected cipher. But what about TLS1.3 where there is no key exchange algorithm, what should the authType value be in that case? How to validate a certificate when using TLS1.3 with this method? I'm using openJDK 8.

Comment: What actual value do you get in `authType`? Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I need to pass in a value to this method. My question is what value should I pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's "UNKNOWN".](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/7fcf35286d52/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/CertificateMessage.java#l1306) Note actual cert-path validation and name check are same as lower protocols; 1.3 server is not specified to use a cert containing a key and (potentially) KeyUsage matching the keyexchange as in lower protocols, merely one that is signature-capable and matches one of the signature_algorithms values offered by the client -- and JSSE client offers all, at least assuming an EC provider is available which is normally the case in j7 up. (1.2, only, specified server cert to match sigalgs *and* keyexchange.)

AFAICS the default validator (i.e. when you use TrustManagerFactory) doesn't actually check this value at all, although [it does apply a constraint for sigalgs when present](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/7fcf35286d52/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java) (i.e.in 1.2 or 1.3). The TLS specs don't require the client to check this, not even 1.3 which generally requires more receiver checking (i.e. antiPostelianism) than earlier versions. (OTOH the default *X509[Extended]KeyManager* does use the similar keyType[s] parameter.)

PS: do you mean you are *calling* the standard (X509)TM to validate the cert? If so you don't need to; JSSE already does. Or do you mean you are *supplying* your own class that `implements X509TrustManager` to *be* called? If so, you should be aware in 7 up (as you've linked) JSSE will *add* 'endpoint-identification' i.e. host name checking where applicable to a supplied X509TM. If you want to control that yourself, you must instead `extends X509ExtendedTrustManager` as linked at the top of the page you linked.

Comment: yeah, I'm using the standard TM to validate the cert. I also want to report on why the cert failed validation which can be found from the exception thrown from this method. Thanks for your answer, I'll try with "UNKNOWN"